# How do I override a property in a non-inheritable class?

Tags: .net, inheritance, overriding

In the MSDN documentation, System.Reflection.Assembly has a property called CodeBase which is defined as overridable.

```
Public Overridable ReadOnly Property CodeBase As String
```

However, if I try to create a new class that inherits System.Reflection.Assembly, I get an error message that tells me it cannot be inherited.  So how can I override this property?

Comment: I'd probably recommend using encapsulation rather than inheritance for this problem.

Comment: I don't want to know why you need to inherit from Assembly ...

Comment: Stefan, I wanted to load an assembly from a byte array whilst setting the codebase property to the location of the original assembly file.  I know you said you don't want to know but I think maybe my reason wasn't as bad as you thought :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do this.

Although the `Assembly` class itself is declared as `public`, it only provides an `internal` constructor. This effectively means that it can only be instantiated (or inherited) from within its own assembly, mscorlib.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can. While `Assembly` is not `sealed` (`NotInheritable` in VB.NET), it has no public constructor; the constructor is `internal` (`Friend` in VB.NET). So it can be inherited, *but only of types within the same assembly as itself* (which is mscorlib).

Comment: Marked this as the answer because it was about 10 seconds faster than the other.

Comment: Not really sure, but I actually think that Luke was a tad faster than I was.

Comment: Could've sworn this one was higher up in the list sorted by oldest.  Oh well, thanks for your honesty ;)